# How to prevent promotion of files with spaces in their names

Tags: version-control, accurev

I would like to prevent the files promoted to an Accurev stream which have spaces in the file name.

*e.g.*

```
My image.png
```

If anybody tries to keep / promote the above file, I would like to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add this logic into the server_preop_trig.  You will add it to both the keep and promote sections of the trigger.

Comment: Hi jstanley , Thanks for your help.
I am new to Accurev . Could you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: The trigger script is found on your server under "accurev install dir/examples".  The trigger script is called server_preop_trig.pl.  Inside this script will give you details how to enable this trigger.  What you will need to do is add logic to the keep/promote sections to fail if a file whose name has a space.

Comment: You probably want to dig into the AccuRev Administrator's Guide on triggers to fully understand what they do and how they function. This will not help with the trigger script code but it is implemented in Perl and fairly simple in how they are constructed.